# Convert string representation of 2 list to list

Tags: python

i want to create a list out of a string.
My String:

```
[[1544434140,asd,asd,asd]]
```

as you can see my String contains a list inside an other list, which is absolutly necessary in case i want to do this:

```
[[1544434140,asd,asd,asd][1544434140,asd,asd,asd]]
```

I already tried:

```
literal_eval(mystring)
```

and

```
eval(mystring)
```

but both throw an Exception like this from ast.literal_eval:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 317, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 348, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 418, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 406, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "/home/dev/requestHandler.py", line 223, in do_GET
    addrequestResult = rh.addRequestToQue(self.path)
  File "/home/dev/requestHandler.py", line 86, in addRequestToQue
    resultOK = self.addToList(request)
  File "/home/dev/requestHandler.py", line 181, in addToList
    doAdd(request, userque, userhistory)
  File "/home/dev/requestHandler.py", line 143, in doAdd
    userque = literal_eval(userque)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 85, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 61, in _convert
    return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 61, in _convert
    return list(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 84, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7fa6751838d0>
```

any idea how i can convert my string with 2 encapsuled list to one list?

Comment: have you defined a variable called `asd` is is that meant to be `'asd'`?

Comment: Also, your example with two inner lists will fail beacuse they are not separated by a `,`.

Comment: Could you indicate the strings with quotes?

Comment: If there are no punctuations like " or , then you will need a language parser. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/parser.html.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I dont have an variable called "asd", it is just an example string that i want out of that list.

Comment: @Graipher oh didnt notice that, you're right. BUT if there is no second entry i don't need the ",". I only tried it on [[1544434140,asd,asd,asd]].

Comment: i just noticed that i could use json.loads and json.dumps to do the exact same.

Comment: @MarcMa: Yes, just wanted to make sure that when you fixed the fact that you either need a variable called `asd` or need to add `""`, you don't immediately have the next problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my Assumption if asd is not a variable and need ',' in flattern lists.If Any let me know

**Try this Format string eval() will work**

```
mystring = "[[1544434140,'asd','asd','asd'],[1544434140,'asd','asd','asd']]"
print eval(mystring)

Result:[[1544434140, 'asd', 'asd', 'asd'], [1544434140, 'asd', 'asd', 'asd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer of @Narendra Lucky does work, but there is a second solution:

```
Mylist = json.loads(MyString)
```